STM32 stall after implementing STOP2 mode. Implementation of a interrupt based keyboard in Nucleo-L412KB
I have implemented a serial keyboard with a Nucleo-L412KB board (bare-metal). The switches are arranged in nine rows (output pins driven high) and seven cols (input pins pulled-down, with interrupts setup for triggering in both rising/falling edges).
When one column fires, the ISR starts a debounce timer (TIM2), and sets two flags 'bouncing' and 'pendingkey'. The ISR for the timer clears the 'bouncing' flag. With those interrupts (GPIOs and TIM2), the main loop does nothing until (!bouncing & pending), in which case it scans the rows, identify the key that has been pressed/released, sends its code via the USART and finally clears the pending flag.
So far the code worked. But now I want the MCU to go to STOP2 mode, and wake up with the EXTI interrupts from the columns. Adding the function stopkbd() into the main loop makes the MCU stall!
The main code is attached:
// main.c
// Copyright (c) 2022-2023 Cesanta Software Limited
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

#include "hal.h"
#include "input-event-codes.h"

#define TKEY0  1LL<<4
#define TKEY1  1LL<<60
#define TKEY2  1LL<<61

static uint8_t keycode[256] = { \
     KEY_ESC, KEY_TAB, KEY_CAPSLOCK, KEY_LEFTSHIFT, KEY_TYPE, KEY_MINUS, KEY_A, KEY_Q, KEY_1, \
       KEY_2, KEY_W, KEY_S, KEY_Z, KEY_LEFTCTRL, KEY_X, KEY_D, KEY_E, KEY_3, \
       KEY_4, KEY_R, KEY_F, KEY_C, KEY_LEFTALT, KEY_V, KEY_G, KEY_T, KEY_5, \
       KEY_6, KEY_Y, KEY_H, KEY_B, KEY_SPACE, KEY_N, KEY_J, KEY_U, KEY_7, \
       KEY_8, KEY_I, KEY_K, KEY_M, KEY_RESERVED, KEY_COMMA, KEY_L, KEY_O, KEY_9, \
       KEY_0, KEY_P, KEY_SEMICOLON, KEY_DOT, KEY_RIGHTALT, KEY_SLASH, KEY_APOSTROPHE, KEY_LEFTBRACE, KEY_MINUS, \
       KEY_EQUAL, KEY_RIGHTBRACE, KEY_BACKSLASH, KEY_RIGHTSHIFT, KEY_RIGHTCTRL, KEY_TYPE, KEY_TYPE, KEY_ENTER, KEY_BACKSPACE, \
       KEY_RESERVED, \
     KEY_ESC, KEY_TAB, KEY_CAPSLOCK, KEY_LEFTSHIFT, KEY_TYPE, KEY_MINUS, KEY_A, KEY_Q, KEY_F1, \
       KEY_F2, KEY_W, KEY_S, KEY_Z, KEY_LEFTCTRL, KEY_X, KEY_D, KEY_E, KEY_F3, \
       KEY_F4, KEY_R, KEY_F, KEY_C, KEY_LEFTALT, KEY_V, KEY_G, KEY_T, KEY_F5, \
       KEY_F6, KEY_Y, KEY_H, KEY_B, KEY_SPACE, KEY_N, KEY_J, KEY_U, KEY_F7, \
       KEY_F8, KEY_I, KEY_K, KEY_M, KEY_RESERVED, KEY_COMMA, KEY_LEFT, KEY_O, KEY_F9, \
       KEY_F10, KEY_UP, KEY_DOWN, KEY_DOT, KEY_RIGHTALT, KEY_SLASH, KEY_RIGHT, KEY_UP, KEY_MINUS, \
       KEY_EQUAL, KEY_PAGEUP, KEY_PAGEDOWN, KEY_RIGHTSHIFT, KEY_RIGHTCTRL, KEY_TYPE, KEY_TYPE, KEY_ENTER, KEY_BACKSPACE, \
       KEY_RESERVED, \
     KEY_ESC, KEY_TAB, KEY_CAPSLOCK, KEY_LEFTSHIFT, KEY_TYPE, KEY_MINUS, KEY_A, KEY_Q, KEY_1, \
       KEY_2, KEY_W, KEY_S, KEY_Z, KEY_LEFTCTRL, KEY_X, KEY_D, KEY_E, KEY_3, \
       KEY_4, KEY_R, KEY_F, KEY_C, KEY_LEFTALT, KEY_V, KEY_G, KEY_T, KEY_5, \
       KEY_6, KEY_Y, KEY_H, KEY_B, KEY_SPACE, KEY_N, KEY_J, KEY_U, KEY_7, \
       KEY_8, KEY_I, KEY_K, KEY_M, KEY_RESERVED, KEY_COMMA, KEY_L, KEY_O, KEY_9, \
       KEY_0, KEY_P, KEY_SEMICOLON, KEY_DOT, KEY_RIGHTALT, KEY_SLASH, KEY_APOSTROPHE, KEY_LEFTBRACE, KEY_MINUS, \
       KEY_EQUAL, KEY_RIGHTBRACE, KEY_BACKSLASH, KEY_RIGHTSHIFT, KEY_RIGHTCTRL, KEY_TYPE, KEY_TYPE, KEY_ENTER, KEY_BACKSPACE, \
       KEY_RESERVED, \
     KEY_ESC, KEY_TAB, KEY_CAPSLOCK, KEY_LEFTSHIFT, KEY_TYPE, KEY_MINUS, KEY_A, KEY_Q, KEY_1, \
       KEY_2, KEY_W, KEY_S, KEY_Z, KEY_LEFTCTRL, KEY_X, KEY_D, KEY_E, KEY_3, \
       KEY_4, KEY_R, KEY_F, KEY_C, KEY_LEFTALT, KEY_V, KEY_G, KEY_T, KEY_5, \
       KEY_6, KEY_Y, KEY_H, KEY_B, KEY_SPACE, KEY_N, KEY_J, KEY_U, KEY_7, \
       KEY_8, KEY_I, KEY_K, KEY_M, KEY_RESERVED, KEY_COMMA, KEY_L, KEY_O, KEY_9, \
       KEY_0, KEY_P, KEY_SEMICOLON, KEY_DOT, KEY_RIGHTALT, KEY_SLASH, KEY_APOSTROPHE, KEY_LEFTBRACE, KEY_MINUS, \
       KEY_EQUAL, KEY_RIGHTBRACE, KEY_BACKSLASH, KEY_RIGHTSHIFT, KEY_RIGHTCTRL, KEY_TYPE, KEY_TYPE, KEY_ENTER, KEY_BACKSPACE, \
       KEY_RESERVED, \
};


uint32_t SystemCoreClock;  // Required by CMSIS. Holds system core cock value
void SystemInit(void) {    // Called automatically by startup code
  clock_init();            // Sets SystemCoreClock
  //stop2_init();
}

static volatile uint64_t s_ticks;  // Milliseconds since boot
void SysTick_Handler(void) {       // SyStick IRQ handler, triggered every 1ms
  s_ticks++;
}

static volatile uint8_t pendingkey;
static volatile uint8_t bouncing; // Global bouncing
static volatile uint8_t coln;     // Holds the column that triggered
static volatile uint8_t keyn;     // Holds the key that triggered
static volatile uint8_t keymod;   // Holds the layer offset
static volatile uint8_t keylock;  // Holds the key locks
static volatile uint16_t rowscan; // Holds the status of the NROWS rows in the active coln
static volatile uint64_t keydown; // Holds the status of the 62 keys

void TIM2_IRQHandler(void) {
   if (TIM2->SR & (1<<0)) {
     TIM2->SR &= ~(1<<0); // Clear UIF update interrupt flag
     bouncing = 0;
     //EXTI->IMR1 |= (1 << 0); // Re-enable the EXTI interrupt, HERE: need to map to the coln EXTI
     TIM2->CR1 &= ~(1<<0);     // Disable timer
   }
}

void kbd_layer(void) {
    if (keydown & TKEY0) {
      keymod = 64;  // Layer-1: While holding TKEY0
      keylock = 0;
      if (keydown & TKEY1) {
        keymod = 128;  // Layer-2: Once TKEY0 + TKEY1
        keylock = 1;
      }
      else if (keydown & TKEY2) {
        keymod = 192;  // Layer-3: Once TKEY0 + TKEY2
        keylock = 2;
      }
    }
    else if (!keylock) {
      keymod = 0;  // Back to Layer-0: Releasing TKEY0
    }
}

void col_IRQ(uint8_t col) {
    startkbd();
    if (pendingkey == 0) {
      pendingkey = 1;
      bouncing = 1;
      coln = col;
      set_triggers(0);
      TIM2->CNT = 0;
      TIM2->CR1 |= (1<<0);    // Enable timer
      set_all_rows(0);
    }
}


void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void) {
  if (EXTI->PR1 & (1 << 0)) {
    EXTI->PR1 |= (1 << 0);
    col_IRQ(0);
  }
}

void EXTI1_IRQHandler(void) {
  if (EXTI->PR1 & (1 << 1)) {
    EXTI->PR1 |= (1 << 1);
    col_IRQ(1);
  }
}

void EXTI3_IRQHandler(void) {
  if (EXTI->PR1 & (1 << 3)) {
    EXTI->PR1 |= (1 << 3);
    col_IRQ(2);
  }
}

void EXTI4_IRQHandler(void) {
  if (EXTI->PR1 & (1 << 4)) {
    EXTI->PR1 |= (1 << 4);
    col_IRQ(3);
  }
}

void EXTI9_5_IRQHandler(void) {
  if (EXTI->PR1 & (1 << 5)) {
    EXTI->PR1 |= (1 << 5);
    col_IRQ(4);
  }
  else if (EXTI->PR1 & (1 << 6)) {
    EXTI->PR1 |= (1 << 6);
    col_IRQ(5);
  }
  else if (EXTI->PR1 & (1 << 7)) {
    EXTI->PR1 |= (1 << 7);
    col_IRQ(6);
  }
}

int main(void) {
  stop2_init();
  gpio_output(LED_PIN);
  gpio_matrix_init();
  set_all_rows(1);
  col_trigger_init();

  uart_init(UART_DEBUG, 115200);
  //uart_init(UART_DEBUG, 9600);
  init_debouncer();

  pendingkey = 0;
  bouncing = 0;
  keydown = 0;
  rowscan = 0;
  coln = 0;
  keymod = 0;
  keylock = 0;

  set_triggers(1);
  while (1) {
    if (!bouncing && pendingkey) {
       rowscan = 0;
       for (int m=0; m < NROWS; m++) {
           gpio_write(ROWS[m], 0);
           gpio_write(ROWS[(m+1)%NROWS], 1);
           while (!gpio_read_out(ROWS[(m+1)%NROWS])) spin(1); // Wait until pin is set
       rowscan |= (gpio_read(COLS[coln]) << (m+1)%NROWS);
       }

       rowscan ^= ((keydown & ((ROWMASK)<<(NROWS*coln)))>>(NROWS*coln));
       if (rowscan && !(rowscan & (rowscan-1)) ) {  // One and only one bit changed
         keydown ^= rowscan << (NROWS*coln);

         // Check the bit that changed
         keyn = NROWS*coln;
         while(rowscan-1){
             rowscan = rowscan >> 1;
             ++keyn;
         }

         gpio_write(LED_PIN, (keydown & (1<<keyn)) >> keyn);
     if (keycode[keyn]>>7) kbd_layer(); // Process special KEY
     else uart_write_byte(UART_DEBUG, keycode[keyn+keymod] + 128*((keydown & (1<<keyn)) >> keyn));
       }

       set_all_rows(1);
       pendingkey = 0; // Now EXTIs can trigger again
       set_triggers(1);
    }
    stopkbd();
  }
  return 0;
}

And this is the hal.h file:
// hal.h
// Copyright (c) 2023 Cesanta Software Limited
// https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00151940-stm32l41xxx42xxx43xxx44xxx45xxx46xxx-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

#ifndef LED_PIN
#define LED_PIN PIN('B', 3)  // Green onboard LED on Nucleo-L432KC
#endif

#define DEBOUNCE_MS 20  // LED blinking period in millis
// Keyboard matrix with 9 rows x 7 cols (mapping 62keys out of 63)
#define NCOLS 7
#define NROWS 9
#define ROWMASK (2<<NROWS)-1
#define ROW0_PIN PIN('B', 0)  // First key
#define ROW1_PIN PIN('B', 1)
#define ROW2_PIN PIN('B', 4)
#define ROW3_PIN PIN('B', 5)
#define ROW4_PIN PIN('B', 6)
#define ROW5_PIN PIN('B', 7)
#define ROW6_PIN PIN('A', 8)
#define ROW7_PIN PIN('A', 11)
#define ROW8_PIN PIN('A', 12)

#define COL0_PIN PIN('A', 0)  // first key
#define COL1_PIN PIN('A', 1)
#define COL2_PIN PIN('A', 3)
#define COL3_PIN PIN('A', 4)
#define COL4_PIN PIN('A', 5)
#define COL5_PIN PIN('A', 6)
#define COL6_PIN PIN('A', 7)

#define ROWSA BIT(8) | BIT(11) | BIT(12)
#define ROWSB BIT(0) | BIT(1) | BIT(4) | BIT(5) | BIT(6) | BIT(7)
#define COLBITS BIT(0) | BIT(1) | BIT(3) | BIT(4) | BIT(5) | BIT(6) | BIT(7)

#pragma once
#include <stm32l412xx.h>

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BIT(x) (1UL << (x))
#define SETBITS(R, CLEARMASK, SETMASK) (R) = ((R) & ~(CLEARMASK)) | (SETMASK)
#define PIN(bank, num) ((((bank) - 'A') << 8) | (num))
#define PINNO(pin) (pin & 255)
#define PINBANK(pin) (pin >> 8)

static const uint16_t ROWS[] = {ROW0_PIN, ROW1_PIN, ROW2_PIN, ROW3_PIN, ROW4_PIN, \
                               ROW5_PIN, ROW6_PIN, ROW7_PIN, ROW8_PIN};

static const uint16_t COLS[] = {COL0_PIN, COL1_PIN, COL2_PIN, COL3_PIN, COL4_PIN, \
                               COL5_PIN, COL6_PIN};

// System clock
enum { AHB_DIV = 1, APB1_DIV = 1, APB2_DIV = 1 };
enum { PLL_HSI = 16, PLL_M = 1, PLL_N = 10, PLL_R = 2 };  // 80 Mhz
//#define SYS_FREQUENCY ((PLL_HSI * PLL_N / PLL_M / PLL_R) * 1000000)
#define SYS_FREQUENCY 16000000
#define APB2_FREQUENCY (SYS_FREQUENCY / APB2_DIV)
#define APB1_FREQUENCY (SYS_FREQUENCY / APB1_DIV)

static inline void spin(volatile uint32_t count) {
  while (count--) (void) 0;
}

enum { GPIO_MODE_INPUT, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT, GPIO_MODE_AF, GPIO_MODE_ANALOG };
enum { GPIO_OTYPE_PUSH_PULL, GPIO_OTYPE_OPEN_DRAIN };
enum { GPIO_SPEED_LOW, GPIO_SPEED_MEDIUM, GPIO_SPEED_HIGH, GPIO_SPEED_INSANE };
enum { GPIO_PULL_NONE, GPIO_PULL_UP, GPIO_PULL_DOWN };
#define GPIO(N) ((GPIO_TypeDef *) (GPIOA_BASE + 0x400 * (N)))

static GPIO_TypeDef *gpio_bank(uint16_t pin) {
  return GPIO(PINBANK(pin));
}

static inline void gpio_toggle(uint16_t pin) {
  GPIO_TypeDef *gpio = gpio_bank(pin);
  uint32_t mask = BIT(PINNO(pin));
  gpio->BSRR = mask << (gpio->ODR & mask ? 16 : 0);
}

static inline int gpio_read(uint16_t pin) {
  return gpio_bank(pin)->IDR & BIT(PINNO(pin)) ? 1 : 0;
}

static inline int gpio_read_out(uint16_t pin) {
  return gpio_bank(pin)->ODR & BIT(PINNO(pin)) ? 1 : 0;
}

static inline void gpio_write(uint16_t pin, bool val) {
  GPIO_TypeDef *gpio = gpio_bank(pin);
  gpio->BSRR = BIT(PINNO(pin)) << (val ? 0 : 16);
}

static inline void gpio_init(uint16_t pin, uint8_t mode, uint8_t type,
                             uint8_t speed, uint8_t pull, uint8_t af) {
  GPIO_TypeDef *gpio = gpio_bank(pin);
  uint8_t n = (uint8_t) (PINNO(pin));
  RCC->AHB2ENR |= BIT(PINBANK(pin));  // Enable GPIO clock
  SETBITS(gpio->OTYPER, 1UL << n, ((uint32_t) type) << n);
  SETBITS(gpio->OSPEEDR, 3UL << (n * 2), ((uint32_t) speed) << (n * 2));
  SETBITS(gpio->PUPDR, 3UL << (n * 2), ((uint32_t) pull) << (n * 2));
  SETBITS(gpio->AFR[n >> 3], 15UL << ((n & 7) * 4),
          ((uint32_t) af) << ((n & 7) * 4));
  SETBITS(gpio->MODER, 3UL << (n * 2), ((uint32_t) mode) << (n * 2));
}

static inline void gpio_input(uint16_t pin) {
  gpio_init(pin, GPIO_MODE_INPUT, GPIO_OTYPE_PUSH_PULL, GPIO_SPEED_HIGH,
            GPIO_PULL_NONE, 0);
}

static inline void gpio_output(uint16_t pin) {
  gpio_init(pin, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT, GPIO_OTYPE_PUSH_PULL, GPIO_SPEED_HIGH,
            GPIO_PULL_NONE, 0);
}

static inline void gpio_matrix_init(void) {
  for (int m=0; m< NCOLS; m++) {
    gpio_init(COLS[m], GPIO_MODE_INPUT, GPIO_OTYPE_PUSH_PULL, GPIO_SPEED_HIGH, GPIO_PULL_DOWN, 0);
  }
  for (int m=0; m< NROWS; m++) {
    gpio_init(ROWS[m], GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT, GPIO_OTYPE_PUSH_PULL, GPIO_SPEED_HIGH, GPIO_PULL_NONE, 0);
  }
}

static inline void col_trigger_init(void) {
  // EXTI0 to EXTI3
  SYSCFG->EXTICR[0] &= ~((2<<16)-1); // Clear first 16 bits
  SYSCFG->EXTICR[0] |= SYSCFG_EXTICR1_EXTI0_PA | SYSCFG_EXTICR1_EXTI1_PA | SYSCFG_EXTICR1_EXTI3_PA;
  // EXTI4 to EXTI7
  SYSCFG->EXTICR[1] &= ~((2<<16)-1); // Clear first 16 bits
  SYSCFG->EXTICR[1] |= SYSCFG_EXTICR2_EXTI4_PA | SYSCFG_EXTICR2_EXTI5_PA | SYSCFG_EXTICR2_EXTI6_PA | SYSCFG_EXTICR2_EXTI7_PA;
  // Rising AND falling edge trigger for each line
  //EXTI->RTSR1 |=  (1 << 0);
  //EXTI->FTSR1 |=  (1 << 0);
  EXTI->RTSR1 |=  COLBITS;
  EXTI->FTSR1 |=  COLBITS;
  NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI0_IRQn, 0);
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI0_IRQn);
  NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI1_IRQn, 0);
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI1_IRQn);
  NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI3_IRQn, 0);
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI3_IRQn);
  NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI4_IRQn, 0);
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI4_IRQn);
  NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI9_5_IRQn, 0);
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI9_5_IRQn);
}

static inline void set_triggers(bool val) {
  EXTI->IMR1 &= ~((2<<16)-1); // Clear first 16 bits
  if (val) EXTI->IMR1 |= COLBITS;
}

static inline void set_all_rows(bool val) {
  uint32_t bitsa = ROWSA;
  uint32_t bitsb = ROWSB;
  GPIO(0)->BSRR = bitsa << (val ? 0 : 16);
  GPIO(1)->BSRR = bitsb << (val ? 0 : 16);
  //return 1; // Check the ODR register to guaranty all set
}

static inline void set_row(uint16_t val) { // Here incorporate the readout of the column and return
  GPIO_TypeDef *gpio = gpio_bank(ROWS[val]);
  gpio->BSRR = BIT(PINNO(ROWS[val])) <<  0;
  //return 1; // Check the ODR register to guaranty all set
}


#ifndef UART_DEBUG
#define UART_DEBUG USART2
#endif

static inline bool uart_init(USART_TypeDef *uart, unsigned long baud) {
  // https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32l432kc.pdf
  uint8_t aftx = 7, afrx = 7;  // Alternate function
  uint16_t rx = 0, tx = 0;     // Pins
  uint32_t freq = 0;           // Bus frequency. UART1 is on APB2, rest on APB1

  if (uart == USART1) {
    freq = APB2_FREQUENCY, RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_USART1EN;
    tx = PIN('A', 9), rx = PIN('A', 10);
  } else if (uart == USART2) {
    freq = APB1_FREQUENCY, RCC->APB1ENR1 |= RCC_APB1ENR1_USART2EN;
    tx = PIN('A', 2), rx = PIN('A', 15), afrx = 3;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

  gpio_init(tx, GPIO_MODE_AF, GPIO_OTYPE_PUSH_PULL, GPIO_SPEED_HIGH, 0, aftx);
  gpio_init(rx, GPIO_MODE_AF, GPIO_OTYPE_PUSH_PULL, GPIO_SPEED_HIGH, 0, afrx);
  uart->CR1 = 0;                          // Disable this UART
  uart->BRR = freq / baud;                // Set baud rate
  uart->CR1 |= BIT(0) | BIT(2) | BIT(3);  // Set UE, RE, TE
  //uart->CR3 |= BIT(8) | BIT(9);  // Set CTSE and RTSE, for RS-232
  return true;
}

static inline void uart_write_byte(USART_TypeDef *uart, uint8_t byte) {
  uart->TDR = byte;
  while ((uart->ISR & BIT(7)) == 0) spin(1);
}

static inline void uart_write_buf(USART_TypeDef *uart, char *buf, size_t len) {
  while (len-- > 0)
    uart_write_byte(uart, *(uint8_t *) buf++);
}

static inline int uart_read_ready(USART_TypeDef *uart) {
  return uart->ISR & BIT(5);  // If RXNE bit is set, data is ready
}

static inline uint8_t uart_read_byte(USART_TypeDef *uart) {
  return (uint8_t) (uart->RDR & 255);
}

//static inline void rng_init(void) {
//  RCC->AHB2ENR |= RCC_AHB2ENR_RNGEN;
//  RNG->CR |= RNG_CR_RNGEN;
//}
//static inline uint32_t rng_read(void) {
//  while ((RNG->SR & RNG_SR_DRDY) == 0) (void) 0;
//  return RNG->DR;
//}

#define UUID ((uint8_t *) UID_BASE)  // Unique 96-bit chip ID. TRM 41.1

// Helper macro for MAC generation
#define GENERATE_LOCALLY_ADMINISTERED_MAC()                        \
  {                                                                \
    2, UUID[0] ^ UUID[1], UUID[2] ^ UUID[3], UUID[4] ^ UUID[5],    \
        UUID[6] ^ UUID[7] ^ UUID[8], UUID[9] ^ UUID[10] ^ UUID[11] \
  }

// t: expiration time, prd: period, now: current time. Return true if expired
static inline bool timer_expired(volatile uint64_t *t, uint64_t prd,
                                 uint64_t now) {
  if (now + prd < *t) *t = 0;                    // Time wrapped? Reset timer
  if (*t == 0) *t = now + prd;                   // Firt poll? Set expiration
  if (*t > now) return false;                    // Not expired yet, return
  *t = (now - *t) > prd ? now + prd : *t + prd;  // Next expiration time
  return true;                                   // Expired, return true
}

// Fill in stack with markers, in order to calculate stack usage later
extern unsigned char _estack, _end;
static inline void stack_fill(void) {
  uint32_t dummy, *p = (uint32_t *) &_end;
  while (p < &dummy) *p++ = 0xa5a5a5a5;
}

static inline long stack_usage(void) {
  uint32_t *sp = (uint32_t *) &_estack, *end = (uint32_t *) &_end, *p = sp - 1;
  while (p > end && *p != 0xa5a5a5a5)
    p--;
  return (sp - p) * sizeof(*p);
}

static inline void init_debouncer(void) {
    TIM2->CR1 &=  ~  (1<<0);    // Disable timer, for now
    TIM2->CR1 |=     (1<<2);    // Set source for events to only overflow, not UG
    //TIM2->CR1 |=   (1<<3);  // Set one pulse (stops after reaching limit)

    RCC->APB1ENR1 |= (1<<0); // Enable clock for TIM2
    //RCC->APB1ENR1 |= RCC_APB1ENR1_TIM2EN;

    TIM2->PSC = 16000-1;     // Set PSC+1 = 160000  pre-scaler, if freq is 16MHz, that is 1ms
    TIM2->ARR = DEBOUNCE_MS; // Set timer to reset after CNT = 100 (that is 100 ms)
    TIM2->DIER |= (1<<0);    // Enable timer interrupt generation
    //TIM2->SR &= ~(1<<0);
    TIM2->EGR |= (1<<0);

    // Enable timer interrupt and set priority
    NVIC_SetPriority(TIM2_IRQn, 1);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);
}


static inline void clock_init(void) {
  //SCB->CPACR |= 15 << 20;  // Enable FPU
  FLASH->ACR |= FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_4WS | FLASH_ACR_ICEN | FLASH_ACR_DCEN;
#if 0
#if 0
  SETBITS(RCC->PLLCFGR, RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM, (PLL_M - 1) << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM_Pos);
  SETBITS(RCC->PLLCFGR, RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN, PLL_N << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_Pos);
  SETBITS(RCC->PLLCFGR, RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLSRC, RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLSRC_HSI);
  RCC->PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLREN;
#else
  RCC->PLLCFGR = BIT(24) | BIT(20) | (PLL_N << 8) | RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLSRC_HSI |
    (7 << 27) | BIT(16);
  RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_PLLON;
#endif
  while (!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY)) spin(1);
#if 0
  SETBITS(RCC->CFGR, RCC_CFGR_PPRE1, (3 + APB1_DIV / 2) << RCC_CFGR_PPRE1_Pos);
  SETBITS(RCC->CFGR, RCC_CFGR_PPRE2, (3 + APB2_DIV / 2) << RCC_CFGR_PPRE1_Pos);
#endif
  RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_SW_PLL;
  while ((RCC->CFGR & RCC_CFGR_SWS) != RCC_CFGR_SWS_PLL) spin(1);
#else
  RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_HSION;
  while (!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_HSIRDY)) spin(1);
  RCC->CFGR &= ~(RCC_CFGR_SW);
  RCC->CFGR |= (RCC_CFGR_SW_HSI);
  while ((RCC->CFGR & RCC_CFGR_SWS) != RCC_CFGR_SWS_HSI) spin(1);
#endif

  //rng_init();                              // Initialise random number generator
  RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_SYSCFGEN;    // Enable SYSCFG
  SystemCoreClock = SYS_FREQUENCY;         // Required by CMSIS
  SysTick_Config(SystemCoreClock / 1000);  // Sys tick every 1ms
}

/* STOP2
 * Voltage regulator: MR is OFF and LPR is ON
 * All clocks OFF except LSI and LSE
 * Wakeup system clock: Either HSI16: if STOPWUCK=1 or MSI if STOPWUCK=0
 * LPMS="010"  SLEEPDEEP=1 and WFI
 * Disabled: TIM2, SysTick timer, USARTs, Flash memory, HSI16,
 */
static inline void stopkbd(void) {
  RCC->APB1ENR1 &= ~RCC_APB1ENR1_USART2EN;   // Disable USART2
  SysTick->CTRL &= ~SysTick_CTRL_ENABLE_Msk; // Disable SysTicks
  RCC->APB1ENR1 &= ~(1UL<<0);                // Disable clock for TIM2
  RCC->AHB2ENR = 0;                          // Disable all GPIO clock
  // RCC->CR &= ~RCC_CR_HSION;               // Disable HSI
  // SLEEP
  SCB->SCR |= SCB_SCR_SLEEPDEEP_Msk;         // Set Cortex SLEEPDEEP bit
  __WFI();
}

static inline void startkbd(void) {
  //clock_init();
  SCB->SCR &= ~SCB_SCR_SLEEPDEEP_Msk;      // Clear Cortex SLEEPDEEP bit
  RCC->APB1ENR1 |= RCC_APB1ENR1_USART2EN;  // Re-enable USART2
  RCC->APB1ENR1 |= (1<<0);                 // Enable clock for TIM2
  RCC->AHB2ENR |= 3;                       // Enable GPIO clocks for bit 0 and 1 (A and B banks)
  SysTick->CTRL |= SysTick_CTRL_ENABLE_Msk;
}

static inline void stop2_init(void) {
  PWR->CR1 &= ~PWR_CR1_LPMS_STOP2_Msk;
  PWR->CR1 |= PWR_CR1_LPMS_STOP2;
  SCB->SCR &= ~SCB_SCR_SLEEPONEXIT_Msk; // Disable re-entering in sleep mode after ISR
  RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_STOPWUCK;       // Select the HSI16 clock for wake up
}

The stop2_init() function sets the STOP2 mode, disables the SLEEPONEXIT (in order to go back to the main loop), and sets the HSI clock as a weak up clock.
When there isn't any key pressed or released, the stopkbd() function sets the SLEEPDEEP bit, disables the clock for the peripherals that are not supported in STOP2, and wait for interrupt (WFI). The interrupt handlers are calling startkbd(), that clears the SLEEPDEEP bit, enable the USART and GPIOs and TIM2.
What am I missing? The MCU is programmed to use only the HSI clock, one timer, the USART2 and the GPIO banks A and B. I have difficulties to figure out whether the board enters in stop2 mode at all. Another thing that I don’t understand is How the GPIOs interrupts can work if all the clocks are stopped (should I provide the LSI for that purpose, while the board is in stop2 mode?).
In the RM0934 manual it’s written: All the peripherals which cannot be enabled in Stop 2 mode must be either disabled by clearing the Enable bit in the peripheral itself, or put under reset state by setting the corresponding bit in the AHB1 peripheral reset register (RCC_AHB1RSTR), AHB2 peripheral reset register (RCC_AHB2RSTR), AHB3 peripheral reset register (RCC_AHB3RSTR), APB1 peripheral reset register 1 (RCC_APB1RSTR1), APB1
peripheral reset register 2 (RCC_APB1RSTR2), APB2 peripheral reset register
(RCC_APB2RSTR).

You might want to set all outputs to LOW (if you are using active low) so pressing any button can trigger the interrupt(s) and after wake up do regular scan (or you can swap inputs and outputs and scan only line that caused interrupt)

Elaborate on "MCU stall". By toggling a GPIO output pin at strategic points and observing using oscilloscope/LA, determine, whether "stall" is at the first entry to stopkbd(), or whether some of the interrupts runs and "stall" happens later on.

By MCU stall I mean the board stops working. The Led in the board doesn't toggle when a key is pressed (as should be). God point with the gpio toggling. It might be helpful.

@Kivv, Don't understand exactly what the advantage would be to use active Low. Are you thinking in reduce power consumption?

That is a lot of code. It ought to be an MRE. (It is also highly redundant, e.g. near "void EXTI1_IRQHandler(void)".)

What I meant is that scan is stopped when you stop mcu. You might have single row (or col) that can wake up the mcu or nothing if everything is deactivated at the time of stop. If you activate all outputs before stop, any key can wake up mcu

@KIIV, The scan is actually done only once per interrupt. Indeed, the idea is to stop the MCU once a key is processed, and wakeup in a key pressed/released event.
